# Server.Transfer - error executing child request

Tags: c#, sitecore7

Using Sitecore 7.2, I want to do a Server.Transfer (Response.Redirect wont do the job here), inside Page_Load of one of my Sublayouts. Its redirecting to a page within my Sitecore site that is accessible OK in a browser.

But the Server.Transfer is throwing the below error

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Error executing child request for /my-account/Renewal messages.]
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal
```

Is there something in Sitecore that is preventing this from working? Is it going to be possible?

Comment: Have you tried Server.TransferRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some resources, such as .cshtml pages, require you use [Server.TransferRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.transferrequest.aspx) to perform an asynchronous execution of the specified URL.

If that doesn't work make sure the resource you are transferring to exists in your website and it isn't inside of another website such as when it is in a child virtual directory or child applicatin.